# Auto arrange irregular shapes inside of artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I have over 500 irregular shapes with different sizes on artboard, total area of them is less than artboar's area . align/arrange all of them and control overlaps manually is not possible , are there any script to re-arrange (put each shape on free space) all these shapes inside of artboard without overlaps ? (maybe with [space filling](http://levitated.net/daily/levEmotionFractal.html) algorithm)

Edit : this picture is good sample for my need. many shapes with different size. [image: this image]

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using this one located on the tab above when two or more object/shapes are selected?

[image]

**If not yet**:

- ## For rows: Select all shapes within a row then click this :

  [image]

Like the following image:

[image]

- ## For the spacing of your shapes within a row: all shapes within a row then click either of the 3 buttons: [image] **It depends if the spacing will depend on your first shape on the left, center or your last shape on the right.**

Like the following image:
[image]

- ## For **Columns:** Select all shapes within a column then click this:  [image]

Like the following image:
[image]

- ## For the spacing of your shapes within a row: all shapes within a row then click either of the 3 buttons: [image]It depends if the spacing will depend on your first shape on the top, center or your last shape on the bottom.**

Like the following image:
[image]

I hope I was able to answer your question.

Comment: +1 for helpful answer but , you used the regular shape ( box , circle , ... )  , my problem has irregular shapes with different size, in that case I should categorize them with size first and then align and distribute them with your solution.

Comment: Since you have irregular shapes what you really want is to distribute spaces ([as here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/5989/52050))

Comment: please check the edit on my question

Comment: Now I understand. I can't find that link that I saw before which is a tutorial how to create an illustration exactly like that but I remember he created and used it as a "pattern" effect .

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be https://svgnest.com/, an open source tool designed for CNC. It's a browser-based vector nesting tool.
You can work with SVG. Check out the Git repo too here https://github.com/Jack000/SVGnest

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use *Window > Align* (check *Show Options*)
If you have a problem with irregular shapes - outline them regular shapes, then group them and align/arrange/distribute. Finally, delete regular shapes.