# How can I distribute many rectangles inside a larger rectangle, minimizing empty space, without rotation?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, composition, posters

I have about 50 rectangular pieces of paper, with dimensions between 1 and 5 inches and different "aspect ratios." I'd like to fit them all inside the smallest rectangle possible. Additional constraints are that each rectangle should not be rotated (imagine they all have an arrow on them, and the arrow must be pointing up) and no rectangle be cropped or resized.

[image]

I've tried approaching this from two angles. First was digital collage software. However, it seems that because collage software are used for digital collages, most if not all don't have options to preserve image size. Many seemingly don't even have options to disable automatic cropping.

Second, I've looked into nesting software used for CNC and laser cutters. This seems more promising, but most do not have an option to disable rotation, most are priced for commercial use by big companies, and many require knowledge of CAD software (no .svg importing).

What software (either standalone or plugin/scripts for Photoshop or Illustrator) could help me with this problem? I'm aware of questions like [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42612/spacing-between-irregular-objects) and [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80495/auto-arrange-irregular-shapes-inside-of-artboard); I'm hoping that better solutions exist for shapes that are irregular, but all rectangular.

Comment: Interesting. May I ask what this is for?

Comment: If no image can be cropped or resized or rotated, then to be honest, I don't see how it would be possible to get such an exact fit inside a rectangle. You can try experimenting using [SVG Nest](https://svgnest.com/test/).  You can set the rotations to 0 in the settings.

Comment: Even after 300 iterations with SVG Nest, the best you can probably get is [something like this](https://imgur.com/j4sOZAL)

Comment: Also note SVG Nest only works with vector objects

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm not sure what the rotation setting on SVGnest does, but it does not prevent rotation from the original orientation. I'm guessing what it does is modify the number of rotations between iterations. https://i.imgur.com/ojIBkwx.png

Comment: Hmm looks like you are right. However, in that case, without rotation, the results would probably be even worse.

Comment: @wavedash the rotation parameter only does something if and only if you set it to 1 before you nest anything. Seems to work as expected if you do. Anyway svgnest isnt computationally ideal for this.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I found a pretty good solution, https://www.cutlistoptimizer.com/

It's basically a nesting program for cutting rectangular pieces of wood from a larger sheet. Because it's designed for wood, there's an option to disable rotating (and it's free). You can get something like 5-10 free optimzation calculations per day, which seems very generous.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this page](http://www.mouseprints.net/Photoshop.html) (direct link to zip [here](http://www.mouseprints.net/old/dpr/PhotoCollageToolkit.zip)).  It's pretty old, but it should do the job.  Use the "BatchPicturePackageNoRotate.jsx" script.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this script works. The first thing it asks for is a template; how do I generate the optimal template?

Comment: @wavedash read through the page's section for "Photo collage and mockup tools".  It explains how to build a template, and offers some templates for download.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know how to manually prepare a template, and then automatically populate it. However, I'm not seeing any documentation on how to automatically make a template.

Comment: I see the problem now - I don't think this script will do what you're looking for.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

This free online tool is worth a look, it should do what you're looking for [CutList Optimizer | WorkshopBuddy](https://workshop-buddy.com/). I've included an example pattern which is pretty close to your example.

[image: An example pattern]

Comment: Thats been answered allready